# Value passed as parameter doesn't work in sql server for built in functions of datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
DECLARE @GET DATETIME
SET @GET= GETDATE()
DECLARE @Val VARCHAR(10)
SET @Val='wk'

--SELECT DATEADD(@Type,2,@GET)

 SELECT DATEPART(wk,GETDATE())  -- WORKING
```

The above line works but when i pass it as a paramter it doesn't work.

```
 SELECT DATEPART(@val,GETDATE())  -- NOT WORKING
```

The interval passed seems to be of other data type.

Answer (score 0):

Make it as `Dynamic Query`

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(500)

DECLARE @Val VARCHAR(10)

 SET @Val='week'  --Quarter, Month

set @sql = 'SELECT DATEPART('+@val+',GETDATE())'

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Or Alternatively you can use this

```
If @val = 'Week'
SELECT DATEPART(Week,GETDATE())
Else If @val = 'Month'
SELECT DATEPART(Month,GETDATE())
....
```

Comment: any other possible way apart from making it dynamic ?

Comment: @Praveen_07 - Updated